# Given x + y = 10, can Excel give me a list of possible x and y?

Tags: excel

Can anyone help me with this problem? I have a more complex equation of course.

Thanks

Comment: There are an infinite number of solutions. Any constraints on x or y?

Comment: Excel can because Math can. Write the function as `y = 10 - x`, then take any random `x` and you can calculate the `y`.

Comment: sorry, simple constraints, x,y>0 and integers!

Comment: If the equation you are interested in is "of course" more complicated, it isn't clear that the utterly obvious solution for `x + y = 10` will usefully generalize. Is there any reason that you aren't describing your actual problem?

Comment: thank you so much! my problem is actually a DCF model with 4 variables and im doing a breakeven analysis, at which i want a sample set of 4 variables giving NPV=0.

this script is gonna be difficult >.< but thanks!

Comment: If you can come up with smallish upper bounds on the variables then you could brute-force all solutions. On the other hand, `n^4` grows rapidly (a trillion by the time n gets to a thousand) so this might become infeasible, especially if it is just a step in a larger problem. If you just want a sample solution, why not just use the built-in solver (which can constrain variables to be integers)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a user defined function in VBA to list the possibilities as a string however you've said that your equation is actually more complex.

For your example of `x + y = 10` you could do something like:

```
Private Function XYPotentials(i As Integer) As String

Dim z As Integer
Dim str As String

For z = 1 To i - 1
    If InStr(str, "(" & z & ", " & i - z & ")") = 0 Then
        str = str & "(" & z & ", " & i - z & "), "
    End If
Next z

XYPotentials = Mid(str, 1, Len(str) - 2)

End Function
```

Then you can simply use the function in excel:

```
=XYPotentials(10)
```

Which will return the following string:

> (1, 9), (2, 8), (3, 7), (4, 6), (5, 5), (6, 4), (7, 3), (8, 2), (9, 1)

And `=XYPotentials(20)` will return:

> (1, 19), (2, 18), (3, 17), (4, 16), (5, 15), (6, 14), (7, 13), (8, 12), (9, 11), (10, 10), (11, 9), (12, 8), (13, 7), (14, 6), (15, 5), (16, 4), (17, 3), (18, 2), (19, 1)

Comment: thank you so much! my problem is actually a DCF model with 4 variables and im doing a breakeven analysis, at which i want a sample set of 4 variables giving NPV=0.

this script is gonna be difficult >.< but thanks!